# Control cursor in 3D

Tags: c#, 3d, kinect

I'm making 3d graphical editor, which will use `Kinect` to screen navigation.
I need to make my own cursor, which will get axis x and axis y coordinates from right hand via Kinect, translate it to computer screen and move cursor to that location.

My real problem is, that I also need coordinates from depth sensor to get coordinates on axis z. Any help will be greatly appreciated. App is developed in `C#` with official `MS Kinect SDK`.

Comment: You can get the z axis coordinate in kinect.What is your problem?

Comment: As @Fyre mentions, the x/y/z coordinates are all very easily accessible.  Every example provided by Microsoft in the Kinect SDK demonstrates how to use them.  What have you tried that is causing problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the right hand will move the cursor you could get the coordinates of the right hand, convert it to color coordinates and place the mouse at the desired coordinate, for example.

First of all, declare your array of skeletons and the coordinate mapper instance
    private Skeleton[] skeletons;
    private CoordinateMapper cm = new CoordinateMapper();

On the AllFramesReady or in the SkeletonFrameready event handle you could to the following:

```
using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
{
 if (skeletonFrame == null)
     return;

    if (skeletons == null || skeletons.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength)
    {
        skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
    }
    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

    if (skeletons.All(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked))
        return;

    Skeleton firstTrackedSkeleton = skeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked).FirstOrDefault();

    CoordinateMapper cm = new CoordinateMapper(YourKinectSensor);
    ColorImagePoint colorPoint = cm.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(first.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

     //Here the variable colorPoint have the X and Y values that you need to position your cursor.
}
```

This is the basics, for a more detailed example i sugest you look ate the samples that comes with the sdk.

Comment: Q: If I just take HandRight object then it has [X,Y,Z] co-ordinates, while using this colorPoint we miss the Z co-ordinate.  In co-ordinate  Mapper class I can map a SkeletonPointToDethPoint and it returns a DepthImagePoint which has depth in integers.  So question is which one is better to use the HandRight.Postion.Z or Depth from  DepthImagePoint.

Comment: Nice question @Mitul I never played with Depht Data in deep, but it could be interesting. Anyway, using ColorPoint information to X and Y and Skeleton only for the Z data could work fine. I think the answer for your question is another question: Whats your application needs?